# Boot of Windows 7 from GPT disk on non EFI motherboard

Tags: windows-7, bios, mbr, gpt, efi

Looks like the answer is no but just to double check... Can I boot Windows 7 SP1 x64 from GPT disk (converted with Windows DISKPART) if my system built on BIOS (non EFI motherboard, ASUS P5WDH Deluxe)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinarily, no. There is one rather awkward workaround, though: You can use the Developer's UEFI Environment (DUET) to run UEFI as a sort of boot loader atop your BIOS. This is difficult to set up, it will slow down your boot process, and it doesn't even work on many computers, so it's really worth considering only as a learning exercise or if you're really desperate (say, if you've got an over-2TiB hard disk and can't add another boot device). If you're really interested, check [this Web page of mine,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/bios2uefi/index.html) which describes the process in detail. (It's far too lengthy to post here.)

Comment: Thanks for this - looks like this is too complicated to go for it in my case, but nice to know that there is at least some solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you even have a *small* MBR drive, you can. A floppy or USB stick will do.

Boot into the Windows install/repair disc. Create the system drive on the stick, and use `bcdboot` to put your boot files on the stick. Add a bootsector with `bootsect`. Change the `{bootmgr}` `device` to `boot`. Boot from stick.

Steps are detailed [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/320700-boot-windows-7-8-gpt-bios-system-no-hybrid-mbrs-duet.html).

Comment: Thanks for another workaround - can be interesting as a technical excercise but not for everyday use. I actually abandoned this idea, or to be more precise decided to get back to GPT disks once I replace my motherboard with one with EFI.

Comment: @Mikhail It's almost not a workaround.. Only auto repair from the DVD will detect anything wrong. MS tools all support it. Of course, it does take a slight bit of effort

Answer (score 0):

Windows does not support booting to a GPT disk unless your using a UEFI BIOS.