# How to make external linux boot disk that can be used in both linux and windows

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, uefi

try to make Linux installed in external harddrive that I can pre-select in boot option to boot it from any machine doesn't matter whether I am using windows or linux machine as my primary OS.
Windos got its UEFI I am not sure about.
Should I make this disk in windows or linux?

Comment: The primary OS of the computer is irrelevant because it won't be loaded if you boot from your external drive.  UEFI is important and your external drive will need to be prepared for that.  You can create the drive in either Windows or Linux.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any link about safe install bootable external linux that will work under UEFI firmware? If I setup as UEFI, for the machine that doesn't have it, will it be a problem?

Comment: UEFI works very well with Linux, internal and external.

Comment: I have read article [link](https://www.dionysopoulos.me/253-portable-ubuntu-on-usb-hdd.html) meantioned about boot issue with windows10 that make it only with this PC. But If I install from windows 7 PC it shouldn't have this issue right?

Comment: The Linux installer will likely check the machine you're using and set up the external drive for UEFI or legacy based on that.  If the machines you will use it with are a mix of UEFI and legacy, there are a few options.  On many UEFI computers you can switch back and forth on the fly if the external drive doesn't match (an old Win 7 computer likely won't know what to do with UEFI).  It is also possible to make the external drive a hybrid that will work with either: https://superuser.com/questions/801515/is-a-hybrid-linux-usb-stick-for-uefi-legacy-bios-possible.

Comment: The article you linked two comments above is for booting Windows from the external. You can disregard it. I use external USB drives formatted with Linux all day long with Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the partition table using GPT (the GUID Partition Table), which is fully supported by Linux and the default for Windows.

Format the drive in FAT32, then install Linux on it.  The native format of flashdrives is FAT32, and it is easily read by both Linux and Windows without any drivers or special apps.  NTFS could be used as well.

However, I have had problems with Windows corrupting ext4 drives with the ext series of drivers to read/write Linux native partitions, so I avoid recommending it until I know how to solve those problems.

Comment: May I ask why do I need to install windows? I only need to create a Linux bootable drive so that I can use to be an OS from any machine with any os.

Comment: The question describes an external hard drive, and doesn't mention anything about needing Windows to be able to read the drive.  Wouldn't one of the Linux filesystems be better (and there are drivers and utilities that enable Windows to use it if needed)?

Comment: When you mentioned https://www.dionysopoulos.me/253-portable-ubuntu-on-usb-hdd.html that led me to think that was what you wanted.

Comment: So the step is 1) convert external drive to GPT 2) format as FAT32 3) I have got a bootable linux sumdrive(linux installation iso converted), so basically I can boot it from any winows machine, then use this bootable disk to install on this specific external disk then way to go?

Comment: Thank you very much. So it has nothing to do with setup ESP and GRUB2 according to that article I have linked right?

Comment: Yes, that's right.